# Show Download file Dialog with Ionic Zip Extract

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in Ionic zip, I have made zip files and want to download it and extract automatically.
I have implemented Extracting functionality, I have a button on web page,clicking on which will extract the zip file and download it to the Path which I have provided in Code, below is my code

```
String TargetDirectory = @"C:\";
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zipfiles"] + filename)))
            {
                zip.ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
                zip.Password = password;
                zip.ExtractAll(TargetDirectory);
            }
```

This code is working fine,I want to show Download Dialog on clicking the button and extract the file on the path which user selects from the Dialog. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We too have faced this particular problem, our issue was that we have number of files to zip and after zip it size comes to somewhere around 2GB's.

How we sorted out.
1. We have a link to download
2. User clicks on it
3. We show a popup having progress wheel
4. We process Zip in background in different thread. (Zip have to be created exclusively for this user only)
5. Once everything is fine, we show a user a download link
6. User download it at any place he wants.

I am not sure if this can help you or not, however it works for us.

Edited to add some code:
We have achieved this using JQuery

```
// Action for download zip link
            $(".downloadZip").click(function () {
                var jqXhr;
                $("a.downloadZipAction").attr("href", "/GetFile?fileName=yourfile.Zip");
                $(".ZipDownLoadBox").show();
                $(".downloadingZip").show();
                $(".DownloadZipLink").addClass("hide");
                var dialogBox = $("#dialogZip").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: '400px',
                    zIndex: 99999,
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        jqXhr.abort();
                    },
                    open: function () {
                        jqXhr = $.post('@Url.Action("DownloadZip")', { uuid: $("#fileName").val() }, function (data) {
                            $(".ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se").remove();
                            $(".downloadingZip").hide();
                            $(".DownloadZipLink").removeClass("hide");
                            $(".downloadZipAction").click(function () {
                                $(dialogBox).dialog("close");
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Yes I have to do same thing, and Zip have created for particular user only
Can you share some code?